# using excel list of web addresses in VBA code for Using dynamic web query with loop

Tags: excel, vba

Please modify my code so that it can work, I have a list of web addresses in excel sheet and i want to use web query based on that list and extract the data in new sheet, need a macro code for that.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim src As Worksheet
Dim tgt As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set src = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set tgt = wb.Sheets("Sheet17")
Dim row As Long
For row = 6 To 15
Cells(row, 12).Value = Cells(row, 12)
Do While src.Cells(row, 12) <> “”
Dim url As String
url = Cells(row, 12)
Range("A1").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=1
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    url, Destination:=Range("$A$5"))
    .CommandType = 0
    .Name = "spg-20161231x10k.htm#Item8FinancialStatementsandSupplementary_1"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = False
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
    .WebTables = "300"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: my link addresses are in sheet2 cells L6:L15, and i want to extract data using web query even if the link addresses change i want vba macro to go to the new addresses that come up in those cells mentioned, and then i want to paste data in new sheet for each link address, means i will have 10 new sheets as i have 10 links in sheet2.

Comment: This is not how things work; first of all try and debug your code, then post a specific question so that we can help.

Comment: can you please see my updated code and guide me on refresh background debug error                           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42858646/this-vba-is-giving-me-a-background-refresh-error-how-can-i-get-rid-of-this-debu

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the table argument for my testing but this construct will work:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GenerateQryTables()

    Dim wb As Workbook, src As Worksheet, url As String, currentRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set src = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With src
        For currentRow = 6 To 15
            DoEvents
            url = .Cells(currentRow, 12)
            If url <> vbNullString Then
                Sheets.Add
                With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
      "URL;" & url, _
         Destination:=Range("A5"))

                    .Name = "Query" & currentRow
                    .FieldNames = True
                    .FieldNames = True
                    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
                    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                End With
            End If
        Next currentRow
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```