# this vba is giving me a background refresh error, how can i get rid of this debug

Tags: excel, vba

this vba is giving me a background refresh error, how can i get rid of this debug

```
Sub Macro21()
'
' Macro21 Macro
'

'
    Dim url As String
    Dim namedt As String
    url = Sheets("sheet18").Range("G2")
    namedt = Sheets("sheet18").Range("I2")

    Range("E2").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://www.sec.gov" & "url", Destination:=Range("$A$10"))
        .Name = "namedt"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "300,301,302"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: is the URL correct?  Do you want it to background refresh?

Comment: We r breaking url just as per sample codes we've, but actually we want to reffer a cell for url address and query/code should repeat data extraction process as recorded by macro, So please help us in setting url value based on cell A1

Answer (score 0):

```
"URL;https://www.sec.gov" & "url", Destination:=Range("$A$10"))
.Name = "namedt"
```

Lose the quotes, thus:

```
"URL;https://www.sec.gov" & url, Destination:=Range("$A$10"))
.Name = namedt
```

I get nothing in A10, but at least it runs.